# como eliminar una fila en un listview c# en visual studio 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, windowsce

actualmente me encuentro desarrollando una aplicación para un dispositivo captador de codigos de barra que funciona con windows CE. por lo cual debo utilizar visual estudio 2008.

el dispositivo captura un codigo de barra y lo guarda en un listview pero necesito poder eliminar una fila de ese listview cuando el usuario seleccione un dato dentro de esta y al apretar el boton eliminar me borre la fila seleccionada.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

actualmente este es mi codigo.

```
private void btEliminar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem item in lvlInfo.Items)
        {

            if (txtFolio.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
            {
                 MessageBox.Show("Debe seleccionar item");
            }
            else

                lvlInfo.Items.Remove();

            }                        

        }
```

me marca error.
Error   1

> Ninguna sobrecarga para el método 'Remove' acepta '0' argumentos.

Comment: Porfavor, edita tu pregunta y agrega la excepción que se dispara, sino es sumamente complicado ayudarte..

Comment: me marca error. Error 1 Ninguna sobrecarga para el método 'Remove' acepta '0' argumentos

Comment: échale un ojo a esto: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8cabccca-f2b9-40c4-9cf5-89cbcbc06f03/remove-selected-items-from-listbox-when-pressed-delete-button?forum=csharplanguage

Comment: Prueba lvlInfo.Items.Remove(item);

Answer (score 1):

lo solucione de la siguiente manera:
nota: algunas funciones de visual 2012-2013 no estan disponibles en 2008.

```
for (int i = lvlInfo.SelectedIndices.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            lvlInfo.Items.RemoveAt(lvlInfo.SelectedIndices[i]);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

El Remove es un metodo de la clase ListViewItem, es decir el item de tu list.-

```
  lvlInfo.Items[i].Remove();
```

Si quieres eliminar el seleccionado, y no tienes algun evento, deberias recorrer el array de items y consultar por `Item.Selected == true`, o buscar en el array de Items Seleccionados `ListView.SelectedItems`.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < lvlInfo.SelectedItems.Count ; i++)
    {
        ListViewItem item = lvlInfo.SelectedItems[i];
        lvlInfo.Items[item.Index].Remove();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Tu código no esta mal, el error que te da es por que no estas pasando el parametro más importante para eliminar que seria el item.

```
    ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection selected = listView1.SelectedItems;//cargas la coleccion de los items seleccionados
    foreach (ListViewItem item in selected)//recorres la lista
    {
        listView1.Items.Remove(item);//eliminas los item del listview
    }
```

Comment: En el código original eso va a producir un `System.InvalidOperationException`, ya que no se puede modificar la colección durante un `foreach`

Comment: Yo pruebo los códigos antes, y no arroja el error que comentas, saludos.